# Función como argumento de otra función Golang

Tags: funciones, go

Tengo una función `f` que recibe como parámetro una función que genera estructuras con el formato de la interfaz `A` (en pocas palabras `f` recibe un generador de estructuras). Le paso un generador de estructuras B pero GO saca un error. Éste es el código:

```
package main

type A interface{
    F()
}
type B struct {}
func (b B) F(){}

func g(A){}
func f(func() A){}


func main(){
    g(B{})
    f(func()B{return B{}})
}
```

El código anterior devuelve el siguiente error y falla en la linea donde trato de invocar una función con otra función:

```
./main.go:15: cannot use func literal (type func() B) as type func() A in argument to f
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrías aclarar que estas tratando de hacer con este codigo?

Comment: La he modificado, estoy leyendo la guia.

Answer (score 1):

Es que el tipo del argumento de la función f (que es en sí mismo la función que devuelve la interfaz `A`) no se acuerda con lo que se pasa en la línea de la `main` que produce la falla (la función que devuelve la struct `B`).

Cámbialo por lo siguiente:

```
func main(){
   g(B{})
   f(func()A{return B{}})
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que Go es el idioma muy estático. Las variables, e incluso el valor devuelto de la función, tienen su tipo predestinado al compilado que nunca se puede cambiar. 
Al contrario a los idiomas como C++ or C#, `B` no se deriva del `A`. En Go, la `interface` es el tipo no relacionado al tipos que la implementan. La interfaz es, más o menos, un par de punteros - uno al dato y el otro a la información sobre su tipo.